# How to calculate standard deviation (σ) for a real time (live) data?

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions, standard-deviation

This is a graph of live data. The red band is a 'VWAP' Volume weighted moving average. I want to calculate standard deviation (1σ) of that red line.
I have used the formula (image attached), where  'M' is that red line. 'SD' is for standard deviation. Which is providing wrong output.(I compared it to other software indicator)
imo main problem area is the 'N', that we take in standard deviation formula. Here, I have considered it as 'cumulative(1)'. I don't know if that's correct.[formula is in dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9XSq.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want standard deviation formula. here in this case , I don't know how to take total number of unit 'N' , as it is a ongoing continuous data set and not discrete.